# How can we use Depth First Search to check whether 2 vertices are connected or not?

Tags: depth-first-search

I am unable to understand how dfs can be used to check whether two vertices in a graph are connected or not( not only directly connected but can also be indirectly connected).

Comment: You can do it by simply defining one node as start-node (origin) and the other as target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the two vertices be `source` and `destination`. Without loss of generality, any of them could be `source`, and the other being `destination`. So the basic idea is, you do a `dfs` starting from the `source` node, and you keep an array to track the status of each node (i.e if they have been visited already or not). When no new node can be visited, the `dfs` will terminate. If the `source` and `destination` are indeed connected, then after running `dfs` from the `source`, the status of `destination` node in the visited array will either be visited (visited status can be represented by `1` or `true`) or not visited (`0` or `false`). It will be `1` or `true` if they are connected and `0` otherwise. Not only does this work for the `destination`, but also all of the other nodes.

```
visited[n] --> n nodes, 0 to n - 1,  initialize with 0 or false values

dfs(source){
    visited[source] = true;
    for(node : adjacencyList[source]){
        if(!visited[node]){
            dfs(node);
        }
    }
}

connected(source){
    dfs(source);
    for(i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i){
        if(!visited[i]){
            // source and i are not connected
        }
    }
}
```